# SQL TRANSACTION Begin End mismatch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, transactions

Although I am able to create stored procedure successfully I am getting `"TRANSACTION BEGIN END MISMATCH"` error upon using it. The stored Procedure works fine when I remove transaction.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Proc_LoanRepayment @LASAcctno     [VARCHAR] (15),
                                   @EntryDate     [VARCHAR] (8),
                                   @ValueDate     [VARCHAR] (8),
                                   @ModeofPayment VARCHAR(20),
                                   @ChqNo         VARCHAR(20),
                                   @ChqDate       VARCHAR(8),
                                   @ChqAmt        MONEY,
                                   @CstBnkNo      VARCHAR(20),
                                   @Cstbnkid      VARCHAR(20),
                                   @CmpBnkNo      VARCHAR(20),
                                   @Cmpbnkid      VARCHAR(20),
                                   @Narration1    [VARCHAR] (100),
                                   @Narration2    [VARCHAR] (100),
                                   @EntryType     VARCHAR(30),
                                   @PostingString [VARCHAR] (max)
AS
    BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @string AS VARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE Cur_A CURSOR FOR
      SELECT *
      FROM   dbo.split(@PostingString, ',')

    OPEN Cur_a

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_a INTO @string

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
      BEGIN
          IF ( object_id('TempDB..#Temp') ) IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
                DROP TABLE #Temp
            END

          --    declare @temp table (srno int identity,items varchar(max))              


          SELECT *
          INTO   #temp
          FROM   dbo.Split(@string, '|')

          DECLARE @LoanNo     AS VARCHAR(20),
                  @BankAcct   AS VARCHAR(20),
                  @TDS        AS MONEY,
                  @LASPAC     AS MONEY,
                  @INTRND     AS MONEY,
                  @INTRAC     AS MONEY,
                  @STAXPLRVL  AS MONEY,
                  @PNLINT     AS MONEY,
                  @OVRDUEINT  AS MONEY,
                  @STMPDTYRVL AS MONEY,
                  @PROFESRVL  AS MONEY,
                  @DOCCHGRVL  AS MONEY,
                  @CHQBNCRVL  AS MONEY

          ALTER TABLE #temp
            ADD srno INT IDENTITY

          SELECT @LoanNo = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 1

          SELECT @bankAcct = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 2

          SELECT @TDS = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 3

          SELECT @LASPAC = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 4

          SELECT @INTRND = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 5

          SELECT @INTRAC = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 6

          SELECT @STAXPLRVL = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 7

          SELECT @PNLINT = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 8

          SELECT @OVRDUEINT = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 9

          SELECT @STMPDTYRVL = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 10

          SELECT @PROFESRVL = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 11

          SELECT @DOCCHGRVL = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 12

          SELECT @CHQBNCRVL = items
          FROM   #temp
          WHERE  srno = 13

          INSERT INTO Tbl_BankEntry
                      (LASAcctno,
                       EntryDate,
                       ValueDate,
                       ModeofPayment,
                       ChqNo,
                       ChqDate,
                       ChqAmt,
                       CstBnkNo,
                       Cstbnkid,
                       CmpBnkNo,
                       Cmpbnkid,
                       Narration1,
                       Narration2,
                       LoanNo,
                       BankAcct,
                       TDS,
                       LASPAC,
                       INTRND,
                       INTRAC,
                       STAXPLRVL,
                       PNLINT,
                       OVRDUEINT,
                       STMPDTYRVL,
                       PROFESRVL,
                       DOCCHGRVL,
                       CHQBNCRVL,
                       status,
                       mkrdt,
                       mkrid,
                       EntryType)
          VALUES     ( @LASAcctno,
                       @EntryDate,
                       @ValueDate,
                       @ModeofPayment,
                       @ChqNo,
                       @ChqDate,
                       @ChqAmt,
                       @CstBnkNo,
                       @Cstbnkid,
                       @CmpBnkNo,
                       @Cmpbnkid,
                       @Narration1,
                       @Narration2,
                       @LoanNo,
                       @BankAcct,
                       @TDS,
                       @LASPAC,
                       @INTRND,
                       @INTRAC,
                       @STAXPLRVL,
                       @PNLINT,
                       @OVRDUEINT,
                       @STMPDTYRVL,
                       @PROFESRVL,
                       @DOCCHGRVL,
                       @CHQBNCRVL,
                       'P',
                       GETDATE(),
                       'c97176',
                       @EntryType   )

          FETCH NEXT FROM Cur_a INTO @string
      END 

    CLOSE cur_a  

    DEALLOCATE cur_a  

    RETURN  

    COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: @MitchWheat does that mean that I can not use transaction in case of Cursor?

Comment: sure you can. But cute puppies die each time you do! :)

Comment: If you are on 2008+ look into table valued parameters rather than splitting strings.

Comment: @MartinSmith Our testing server is 2008 but this project will be going live on 2005 so I am gonna have to stick to splitting strings. I know it sucks. Btw a colleague of mine argues that we can use TVP in 2005, is that true? Because my google-fu says it isnt.

Comment: There's also *no* guarantee that doing `SELECT ... INTO #temp` and *then* adding an IDENTITY column will mean that the "first" row from the `SELECT` (which is ill-defined in and of itself in the absence of `ORDER BY`) will be assigned the identity value 1. So most of this procedure is based on coincidence rather than solid guarantees.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oh no! what do you suggest?

Comment: @Arbaaz - Your split function should return the index of the item directly. No TVPs in 2005 but you could probably do `dbo.split(@PostingString, ',') ... CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(@string, '|')` to get rid of the cursor. See [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) for some example functions.

Comment: I would suggest using XML or (if available) table-valued parameters (TVP), rather than attempting to post structural data as a string containing two levels of delimiters - i.e. use datatypes that natively support passing multiple, related data items. You can then re-write the whole stored proc as a single `INSERT...SELECT` that (in part) queries the TVP or XML structure appropriately.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever As I stated earlier in my previous comment , I am dealing with 2005. So no TVP for me. :/ I do not know the XML approach . Plus it will be time consuming having to re write the procedure. I would like to avoid re writing it for now unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: But you need to compare that with how time consuming it will be to clean things up later if the wrong data has been inserted into the wrong columns. (Especially since you seem to be working with a lot of numeric data - difficult to spot that this situation has even happened). I would recommend the XML approach.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what if I replace alter temp table with  `SELECT identity(int,1,1) as 'SrNo', *
          INTO   #temp
          FROM   dbo.Split(@string, '|')` can it still cause problem?

Comment: This is quite an old [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/273586) from the 2000 era, but I don't think they've done anything to provide a stronger contract on newer versions. It starts on the assumption that you're using an `ORDER BY` clause to *attempt* to control the assignment order (which your newest attempt doesn't), but even then points out that `SELECT ... INTO ...` will not respect any `ORDER BY` clause. Only `INSERT ... SELECT` will, but you *need* that `ORDER BY` - and your `Split` function doesn't give you a column to do that, I believe.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is the function I am using..
Please take a look .. http://forums.asp.net/t/1941228.aspx?Split+value+in+sql+server

Comment: If I add a srno identity column the table variable inside the function then I guess it could be solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RETURN` statement is before your `COMMIT` statement.

Suggest you look into @Martin Smith's sugegstion of using table valued parameters rather than splitting strings (SQL Server 2008+), and @ Damien_The_Unbeliever's suggestion of the expected ordering.

Also, try to rewrite procedure so that it doesn't require a cursor, and that you do the least amount possible of work inside the transaction.

Also, look at `TRY/CATCH`  and checking whether there is an active transaction (`@@TRANCOUNT`) before commiting.

Comment: Estimated Time of Marking your Answer: 9 mins!

Comment: Please take a look at Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment. I test this procedure a number of times at every time The order of the rows was the same when i altered my #temp table. But is it possible that it might cause problem?